# Subtract 1 from all data in an column in sql

Tags: sql, subtraction

Hi I need to write code to add another column to the right subtracting 1 from the column 'policy suffix'. I'm stumped on this one. Any ideas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGyk7.png)

Comment: paste the data in a table and also the desired output

Comment: can you show us what you have tried as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using a select statement.

```
SELECT policyID,
       policyNum,
       PolicyPrefix,
       PolicySuffix,
       PolicySuffix - 1 AS PolicySuffixLess1
FROM yourtable;
```

To get your concatenated field, you can use common table expression for the initial query then select your desired fields from the cte.

```
WITH #CTEPolicies AS (
SELECT *, ap.PolicySuffix - 1 AS priorpolicysuffix
FROM #ActivePolicies
)
SELECT ap.policyID, ap.policyNum, ap.PolicyPrefix, 
       ap.PolicySuffix, ap.priorpolicysuffix,
       CONCAT(ap.PolicyPrefix, '-', ap.priorpolicysuffix) AS priorpolicynumber
FROM #CTEPolicies ap
```

Comment: Does that add a new column? I'd like to create a column showing policysuffix - 1

Comment: Yes it does. That new column is called "PolicySuffixLess1" in this example

Comment: That worked! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Could you please mark it as the answer. Thanks

Comment: Next step would be to add prior policy. I tried this but it's not working

Comment: select    ap.policyID
      , ap.policyNum
      , ap.PolicyPrefix
      , ap.PolicySuffix
      , (ap.PolicySuffix  - 1) as priorpolicysuffix
      , (ap.PolicyPrefix + '-' + priorpolicysuffix) as priorpolicynumber 


from     #ActivePolicies                                 as ap

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, PostgreSQL or MySQL, etc?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: I have added another version of the code to the previous answer.

Comment: Were you able to take a look at merging the 2 columns? I'm getting a message that PriorPolicySuffix is not a valid name

Comment: Yes, I added a new code to my initial solution. You can check it out.

Comment: Sorry but what is CTEpolicies? Does that replace #ActivePolicies?

Comment: No, it doesn't replace it at all. It's similar to a subquery but in this case it is a temporary named result set which we referenced within our SELECT statement. It is very useful. You can read it up later. It is called Common Table Expressions (CTE).